# Dynamic CRM licensing

Tags: crm, licensing, dynamics-crm-2016

I am developing a helper CRM solution and want to upload it to Microsoft Appsource. I want to apply licensing for it, please tell me some instructions or links to any article introduce about how to do this.

Possible strategy:

```
License contains "valid until" date (encrypted)
Unique name of the CRM organization must be encoded in the license and checked in the solution, so that the license cannot be used in other environments (only in the one with the right organization).
Validity date is checked every time the solution is used
License must be encrypted/signed, so that it cannot be tweaked.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this slide for instruction: http://www.slideshare.net/marcoamoedo/building-a-licensing-strategy-for-crm-isv-solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed your app then to register it on Microsoft AppStore, you will have to follow certain steps in order to get listed right there. The procedure in brief is given below:

Step1: Firstly review the Microsoft AppSource guidelines and requirements, which keep on changing and updated time to time.

Step2: After reviewing the guidelines you will have to submit your app for pre-approval. Here you will have to provide general information of your company, name of your app and a general high level description. As a revert mail you will receive approval mail from Microsoft.

Step 3: Sign up for Microsoft Development Center account as individual or student or as a company or partner. Here individual or student account cost $19 USD, while company account costs $99 USD

Step 4: Now register and reserve your app name on Microsoft AppSource
Above steps can be followed by anyone. 
In case if you don’t know and familiar with the complete process, then you can take the help of any service provider and with their help you can easily register any app.